# Python function 'print' not working with Scapy in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: python, intellij-idea, output, scapy

I have installed **Python 2.6** and **Scapy 2.2** in a **Windows 7** machine. The installation is fine and I am able to run Scapy from command prompt.

I am using the **IDE 'IntelliJ'** as the editor. However the following piece of code doesn't return any output, although things are syntactically correct.

```
from scapy.all import * 

print "Hello"             #This line has no output
```

---

Interestingly, when I tried redirecting the standard output **sys.stdout** to a file, it works by logging the output to the file!

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys

sys.stdout = open('outfile', 'w')

print "Hello"     #This line writes 'Hello' to 'outfile'
```

---

Please let me know if there is possibly some way to have the output in the output console as in the normal case with Python ( without Scapy), rather than redirecting the outputs to a separate file.